# customize marker icon in marker clustering in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, markerclusterer

Is there any way to change default marker icon in marker clustering?

Here is my code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up the cluster manager with a supplied icon generator and renderer.
    id<GMUClusterAlgorithm> algorithm = [[GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm alloc] init];
    id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];
    id<GMUClusterRenderer> renderer = [[GMUDefaultClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:googleMapView
                                                                    clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];
    clusterManager = [[GMUClusterManager alloc] initWithMap:googleMapView
                                                  algorithm:algorithm
                                                   renderer:renderer];

    // Register self to listen to both GMUClusterManagerDelegate and
    // GMSMapViewDelegate events.
    [clusterManager setDelegate:self mapDelegate:self];

}

- (void)loadView {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    _camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:29.3117
                                          longitude:47.4818
                                               zoom:8];
    googleMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:_camera];
    googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    googleMapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    googleMapView.delegate = self;

    self.view = googleMapView;
}

-(void)setLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
    [googleMapView animateToLocation:center];
    [googleMapView animateToZoom:12];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"29.0827,48.1363",
                             @"29.2679,47.9927",
                             @"29.348706, 48.092425",
                             @"29.340925, 48.088477",
                             @"29.324912, 48.089850",
                             @"29.330599, 47.990630",
                             @"29.300364, 47.960589",
                             @"29.271917, 47.918017",
                             @"29.3032,47.936", nil];

    //remove all clusters before adding clusters
    [clusterManager clearItems];

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake ([[array[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","][0] floatValue], [[array[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","][1] floatValue]);

        // Add items to the cluster manager.
        NSString *name = nil;//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", i];
        id<GMUClusterItem> item =[[POIItem alloc] initWithPosition:center
                                                              name:name];
        [clusterManager addItem:item];
    }
    // Call cluster() after items have been added
    // to perform the clustering and rendering on map.
    [clusterManager cluster];
}
```

Please guide me...

Comment: If you have a version > 1.1.0 [see my answer here ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560077/5792077)

Comment: If you have a version > 1.1.0 [see my answer here ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560077/5792077)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you used google-maps-ios-utils. The problem is that there is no API for change marker's icon yet. You can only do it directly in the code of the library. I've pasted my custom code inside the method

```
- (GMSMarker *)markerWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position
                         from:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)from
                     userData:(id)userData
                  clusterIcon:(UIImage *)clusterIcon
                     animated:(BOOL)animated{
//...
    if (clusterIcon != nil) {
        marker.icon = clusterIcon;
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    } else {
    if([[marker.userData class] isSubclassOfClass:[POIItem class]]){
        POIItem *item = (POIItem *)marker.userData;
        MarkerIcon* markerView = (MarkerIcon *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MarkerIcon" owner:marker options:nil][0];
        marker.iconView = markerView;
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    }
   }
}
```

It is not a good way to change the code like this. But I could not find better solution for that moment.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but the method will over ride when i refresh my pod files..

Comment: I added this library manually, because I could not install it via Cocoapods. (it conflicted with use_framework directive). So I customized it a lot. But of course it is not a best practise to do the things like that and alter source code directly.

Comment: @Marina, Can i set different icon for individual marker based on category using above code?

Answer (score 1):

I have already sovled this question.

I used googleMaps Api version:8.1.

Here is my code...

```
#import "Clustering/GMUClusterItem.h"

// Point of Interest Item which implements the GMUClusterItem protocol.
@interface POIItem : NSObject<GMUClusterItem>

@property(nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D position;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name;

- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position name:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

1.creat the map.

```
@interface BasicViewController ()<GMUClusterManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate,
                                  GMUClusterRendererDelegate>
@end

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ClusterAlgorithmMode) {
  kClusterAlgorithmGridBased,
  kClusterAlgorithmQuadTreeBased,
};

@implementation BasicViewController {
  GMSMapView *_mapView;
  GMUClusterManager *_clusterManager;
}

- (void)loadView {

    //创建地图
  GMSCameraPosition *camera =
      [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:kCameraLatitude longitude:kCameraLongitude zoom:10];

  _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

  self.view = _mapView;
}
```

2.creat GMUClusterManager object.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

    //添加标注算法方式
    id<GMUClusterAlgorithm> algorithm = [self algorithmForMode:kClusterAlgorithmQuadTreeBased];

    //标注icon
    id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [self iconGeneratorWithImages];//[self defaultIconGenerator];

   // CustomClusterIconGenerator *iconGenerator = [[CustomClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];

  GMUDefaultClusterRenderer *renderer =
      [[GMUDefaultClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:_mapView
                                    clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];
  renderer.delegate = self;

  _clusterManager =
      [[GMUClusterManager alloc] initWithMap:_mapView algorithm:algorithm renderer:renderer];

  // Generate and add random items to the cluster manager.
    //将标注添加到地图上
  [self generateClusterItems];

  // Call cluster() after items have been added to perform the clustering and rendering on map.
    //展示
  [_clusterManager cluster];

  // Register self to listen to both GMUClusterManagerDelegate and GMSMapViewDelegate events.
  [_clusterManager setDelegate:self mapDelegate:self];

  UIBarButtonItem *removeButton =
      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Remove"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                      target:self
                                      action:@selector(removeClusterManager)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[ removeButton ];
}
```

3.in method :

```
/*You can set marker image here

 if [marker class] is POIItem.

 */

- (void)renderer:(id<GMUClusterRenderer>)renderer willRenderMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {

  if ([marker.userData isKindOfClass:[POIItem class]]) {

    POIItem *item = marker.userData;

    marker.title = item.name;

    ******marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"register"];******

  }
}
```