# Custom Marker using GMUClusterManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, markerclusterer

I want to display Custom marker using `GMUClusterManager`. I followed all steps for marker clustering [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering).

but there is blue and red color Icon like this.
[image]

**But when I Zoom in that map it display only red color Marker but I don't want that.**

there is instance method where I have implemented my logic but no use.

```
    - (instancetype)initWithMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView clusterIconGenerator:(id<GMUClusterIconGenerator>)iconGenerator
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        GMSMarker *marker= [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.0, 75.30)];

        UIView *customMarker =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 40)];
        customMarker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        marker.iconView = [self EmployeeMarker:0] ;
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
        marker.map = mapView;
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIView *)EmployeeMarker:(int)labelTextInt{
    UIView *customMarker =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 40)];
    UIImageView *imgViewCustomMarker = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 24, 25)];
    imgViewCustomMarker.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconMapUser.png"];
    [customMarker addSubview:imgViewCustomMarker];
    UIView *viewRatingCustom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 40, 15)];
    viewRatingCustom.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:192.0/255.0 green:192.0/255.0 blue:192.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UILabel *lblRatingEmployees = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 1, 17,8)];
    lblRatingEmployees.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:150.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    lblRatingEmployees.text = @"1";
    lblRatingEmployees.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10];
    [lblRatingEmployees sizeToFit];
    [viewRatingCustom addSubview:lblRatingEmployees];
    UIImageView *imageViewStar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 3, 10, 8)];
    imageViewStar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconBlueStar.png"];
    [viewRatingCustom addSubview:imageViewStar];
    [customMarker addSubview:viewRatingCustom];
    return customMarker;
}
```

I have used this method for display possible number of Marker that is by default red.

```
id<GMUClusterAlgorithm> algorithm = [[GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm alloc] init];

id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];


id<GMUClusterRenderer> renderer =
  [[GMUDefaultClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:_mapView
                                clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];

_clusterManager =
  [[GMUClusterManager alloc] initWithMap:_mapView algorithm:algorithm renderer:renderer];

 // Generate and add random items to the cluster manager.

// [self generateClusterItems];


for (int i = 0; i<latitudeArray.count; i++) {

    id<GMUClusterItem> item =

    [[POIItem alloc]initWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue], [[longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]) name:@"Name"];

    [_clusterManager addItem:item];
}
```

Adde delegates and also cluster method.

```
 [_clusterManager cluster];
 [_clusterManager setDelegate:self mapDelegate:self];
```

**So please help me for adding custom marker in place of red that is in default.**

Comment: Check https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/CustomMarkers.md
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/21

Answer (score 7):

You need to create custom class, which conforms to  `GMUClusterIconGenerator` protocol:

CustomClusterIconGenerator.h file

```
@interface CustomClusterIconGenerator : NSObject
<GMUClusterIconGenerator>

@end
```

CustomClusterIconGenerator.m file

```
@implementation CustomClusterIconGenerator

- (UIImage *)iconForSize:(NSUInteger)size {
    // Return custom icon for cluster
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Custom Cluster Image"];
}

- (UIImage *)iconForMarker {
    // Return custom icon for pin
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Custom Marker Image"];
}

- (CGPoint)markerIconGroundAnchor {
    // If your marker icon center shifted, return custom value for anchor
    return CGPointMake(0, 0);
}

- (CGPoint)clusterIconGroundAnchor {
    // If your cluster icon center shifted, return custom value for anchor
    return CGPointMake(0, 0);
}

@end
```

and then then, instead of

```
id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];
```

use

```
CustomClusterIconGenerator *iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];
```

Here is example from my project:
[image]

Comment: CustomClusterIconGenerator iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];
 at this place there is error.

Comment: iconForMarker is not working.. as clusterd marker work using this code - (UIImage *)iconForSize:(NSUInteger)size

Comment: @MadBurea sorry, there was a typo. Should be `CustomClusterIconGenerator *iconGenerator`. I updated answer.

Comment: @MadBurea about `iconForSize` - maybe library was updated since my last usage. This is fine. Feel free to use `iconForSize`. You always can look at the `GMUClusterIconGenerator` protocol declaration :-)

Comment: iconForSize is used for That Big red and green Circle Cluster. Not for Marker that is displayed after Zoom in or Out. as i want to create custom Marker not BIG RED GREEN CLUSTER. so there is no use of it.

Comment: @MadBurea `iconForMarker` is used for MARKER and `iconForSize` is used for CLUSTER

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 4.2** :

add this exstention to your controller and be sure that your controller is the delegate of `GMUClusterRendererDelegate` :

`willRenderMarker` will call each time a marker going to be render (both cluster marker and clusterItemMarker so you can check it by simple if).so you can modify it's icon and etc before showing it to user

```
extension YourController: GMUClusterRendererDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        // if your marker is pointy you can change groundAnchor
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        if  let markerData = (marker.userData as? PersonMarker) {
           let icon = markerData.imageURL
           marker.iconView = CustomMarkerView(forUrl: url)
        }
    }
}
```

And PersonMarker is your marker class that subclass `NSObject` and `GMUClusterItem` : *(you can use default class of `GMUClusterItem` but if you need some other properties you can subclass it)*

```
class PersonMarker: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {

  var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var imageURL : String?
  var name: String?
  var userdId: String?
  var lastSeen: String?

  init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, url: String?, name: String?, userId: String?, lastSeen: String?) {
      self.position = position
      self.imageURL = url
      self.name = name
      self.userdId = userId
      self.lastSeen = lastSeen
  }

}
```

You can add `PersonMarker` to your `GMUClusterManager` like this :

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item.latitude!, longitude: item.longitute!)
let person = PersonMarker(position: position, url: item.user?.avaterUrl, name: item.user?.name, userId: item.user?.userId, lastSeen: item.lastUpdate)
clusterManager.add(person)
```

Comment: let renderer = CustomRendererMarkers(mapView: mapView,
                                             clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        renderer.delegate = self

Answer (score 4):

You need custom class implementing `GMUClusterIconGenerator` with designed `func icon(forSize size: UInt) -> UIImage!` method which returns `UIImage` for your cluster.

I suggest creating view and functionality to add designed label with cluster's title to it and then creating `UIImage` from your `UIView`.

Then you'll be able to create your custom cluster generator like this:

```
let iconGenerator = ClusterIconGenerator()
```

---

Example result:

[image]

---

Working generator:

```
class ClusterIconGenerator: NSObject, GMUClusterIconGenerator {

    private struct IconSize {

        private let initialFontSize: CGFloat = 12
        private let fontMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.1

        private let initialSize: CGFloat = 25
        private let sizeMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.18

        /**
         Rounded cluster sizes  (like 10+, 20+, etc.)
         */
        private let sizes = [10,20,50,100,200,500,1000]

        let size: UInt

        /**
         Returns scale level based on size index in `sizes`. Returns `1` if size doesn't have rounded representation
         */
        private var scaleLevel: UInt {
            if let index = sizes.lastIndex(where: { $0 <= size }) {
                return UInt(index) + 2
            } else {
                return 1
            }
        }

        /**
         Returns designed title from cluster's size
         */
        var designedTitle: String {
            if let size = sizes.last(where: { $0 <= size }) {
                return "\(size)+"
            } else {
                return "\(size)"
            }
        }

        /**
         Returns initial font size multiplied by recursively created multiplier
         */
        var designedFontSize: CGFloat {
            let multiplier: CGFloat = (1...scaleLevel).reduce(1) { n,_ in n + n * fontMultiplier }
            return initialFontSize * multiplier
        }

        /**
         Returns initial `CGSize` multiplied by recursively created multiplier
         */
        var designedSize: CGSize {
            let multiplier: CGFloat = (1...scaleLevel).reduce(1) { n,_ in n + n * sizeMultiplier }
            return CGSize(width: initialSize * multiplier, height: initialSize * multiplier)
        }

    }

    /**
     Returns image based on current cluster's size
     */
    func icon(forSize size: UInt) -> UIImage! {

        let iconSize = IconSize(size: size)

        let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: iconSize.designedSize)

        let view = UIView(frame: frame)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = iconSize.designedSize.height / 2
        view.backgroundColor = .green

        let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = iconSize.designedTitle
        view.addSubview(label)

        return view.asImage
    }

}

extension UIView {

    var asImage: UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.1.0, new features were added for easy customization of markers ([read more](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/CustomMarkers.md)).

You can add the `GMUClusterRendererDelegate` and `GMUDefaultClusterRenderer.h` and add the method `- (void)renderer:(id<GMUClusterRenderer>)renderer willRenderMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;`

There, you can customize your markers and clusters. For example:

```
- (void)renderer:(id<GMUClusterRenderer>)renderer willRenderMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    if ([marker.userData conformsToProtocol:@protocol(GMUCluster)]) {
        marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"custom_cluster_image.png"];
    }else if ([marker.userData conformsToProtocol:@protocol(GMUClusterItem)]) {
        marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"custom_marker_image.png"];
    }
}
```

Remember to set the delegate properly:

```
id<GMUClusterRenderer> renderer = [[GMUDefaultClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:_mapView clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];
((GMUDefaultClusterRenderer *)renderer).delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the tutorial - [Marker Clustering with Google's Utility library for Maps SDK (Google-Maps-iOS-Utils)](http://studyswift.blogspot.in/2016/07/marker-clustering-with-googles-utility.html), this present a perfect sample on the things you want to implement on your app. There are also Google [sample codes](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/tree/1.0.0/samples) from the [blog](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/07/announcing-marker-clustering-in-google.html) that you might want to try. Lastly there was an issue reported in github about [Way to customize individual markers added to cluster manager?](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/21), it might help you understand how to customize the markers in GMUClusterManager. Hope this helps.