# How to make marker clustering with custom markers in GoogleMaps for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm a beginner in iOS development.
I added a GoogleMaps on my app, I can cluster the default markers of GoogleMaps but when I custom markers by an image from my computer, the custom markers can't cluster.
Someone can help me to do it in Swift 3?

I show you a part of my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

mapView = GMSMapView(frame: view.frame)
mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 48.898902, longitude: 2.282664, zoom: 12.0)
mapView.mapType = .normal
mapView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(mapView)

if isClustering {
    var iconGenerator: GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator!
    if isCustom { // Here's my image if the event are clustered
        var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "m1.png")!, UIImage(named: "m2.png")!, UIImage(named: "m3.png")!, UIImage(named: "m4.png")!, UIImage(named: "m5.png")!]
        iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator(buckets: [10, 20, 50, 100, 200], backgroundImages: images)
    } else {
        iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
    }

    let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
    let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)

    clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm, renderer: renderer)
    clusterManager.cluster()
    clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
} else {
}

// Here's my first custom markers (I don't write here others for simple code)
let firstLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.898902, 2.282664)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: firstLocation)
marker.icon = UIImage(named: "pointeurx1") //Apply custom marker
marker.map = mapView
}

func clusterManager() {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following topic :
[How to cluster custom icons markers in GoogleMaps for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374164/how-to-cluster-custom-icons-markers-in-googlemaps-for-ios)
[How to clustered markers from Firebase in GoogleMaps for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348627/how-to-clustered-markers-from-firebase-in-googlemaps-for-ios/46381671#46381671)

You could find a good answer because I had the same issue last week, just follow these advices.
Hope it helps you a lot

Comment: Yes thank you very much, it helps me a lot because my issue it's for now concerning Firebase too

Comment: Now check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928566/5790492 and https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/CustomMarkers.md